# Google sheets, scatter plot, multiple datasets, with datapoint labels

Tags: google-sheets

I want to create a scatterplot in Google sheets with multiple datasets, and yet still be able to add data labels for each data point. Additionally, it's two independent axis, which means some X values will have multiple Y values.

Example sheet:
This sheet is almost what I want, except I want data labels to show up beside each point and I also want to do multiple different color datasets on the same plot. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1EZ78WNVvvpggP8L52H-yuh-ICJEkd9XCOrX752nHw1I/edit?usp=sharing

[image]

Comment: no idea what you want... add more info + sheet + desired output + some images + your attempts

Comment: @MARKMYANSWER I added an example sheet. It's almost what I want, except I want data labels to show up beside each point and I also want to do multiple different colour datasets on the same plot. Does that make sense? Let me know if you need any more info.

Answer (score 0):

If by "add data labels for each data point" you mean "adding labels from **A** column to each individual point" - then that is not possible. you can add only values as a label for each data point.

As for "two independent axis" - this can be easily achieved by adding new series from another column. All the above would look like:

[image]

From there you can add trendlines or customize each individual data point by changing color, size and shape:

[image]

If you will re-shape your table a bit you could do this:

[image]

Of course, if you really want so you could add custom label per each data point manually by **inserting a drawing**:

[image]

---

## demo sheets: [one](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-P_n9N4IrpDr5Lw1CbkpJwXCoOlw4_-8T7Clpf5PExw/edit#gid=673577062), [two](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-P_n9N4IrpDr5Lw1CbkpJwXCoOlw4_-8T7Clpf5PExw/edit#gid=1853509428)